# Installing an IGH in a Trek District SSB

Tags: internally-geared-hub, trek, belt-drive

I own a [Trek District SSB](https://www.trekbikes.com/us/en_US/bikes/district-ssb/p/1361000-2016/), which uses Trek's proprietary belt drive system. I'd wanted a bike with an internal gear hub, but they only offered [a 3-speed version](https://www.trekbikes.com/us/en_US/bikes/district-igh-3/p/1364000-2016/) as an upgrade, so I decided to buy the SSB and upgrade it myself to something a little beefier.

The SSB has the same frame as the IGH 3, so it already has the cable guides for the hub. I'm going to take my bike to a local community shop to do the conversion, so I should have people on hand to help me with any problems I run into. What I am looking for help with is my shopping list (although warnings and gotchas are welcome).

The IGH 3 claims to use a Shimano Nexus 3-speed hub in the specs, but shows a picture of a Shimano Alfine hub. Would [this](https://www.amazon.ca/Shimano-Alfine-8-Speed-Internal-Bicycle/dp/B01L9FYWZS/ref=sr_1_1?ie=UTF8&qid=1497974241&sr=8-1&keywords=shimano+alfine) work, plus [this shifter](https://www.amazon.ca/Shimano-Alfine-8-Speed-Rapidfire-Shifter/dp/B00A438NO8/ref=sr_1_2?ie=UTF8&qid=1497974241&sr=8-2&keywords=shimano%2Balfine&th=1&psc=1)? Will I be able to swap the drivetrain components over from the SSB to the new hub, or do I need to order replacements for anything?

(Referring to [this question](https://bicycles.stackexchange.com/questions/31122/which-multi-speed-hub-should-i-upgrade-my-trek-district-to), it sounds like an Alfine hub should be compatible. I'm still uncertain about exactly which other components I'll need to order.)

Comment: You should make sure to check if the hub spacing is the same. The hub you linked to has a 135 mm hub width, and your bicycle probably has the same as it has disk brakes, but it's probably best to measure first to be sure that it will fit properly. Measure the space inside the rear dropouts.  Also, relacing an entire wheel is difficult if you've never done it before, and you may need different spokes as the large size of the IGH will require you to use shorter spokes to reach the rim.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Checked with Trek, and that is a 135mm spaced frame, so yes, that hub should work fine with it.  I would make sure of the interface for the belt drive "cog" on the rear wheel, make sure it will work with that hub.  Otherwise, that Alfine should be very good.  That shifter should work fine with that hub too.  Making that interface question the only issue I see other than building the wheel if that's your plan.  If you've never done it before, be aware it's a lot more involved than it appears.

Comment: Thanks doing the research on the frame! I'm aware that building a wheel is a lot of work (even though I've never done it before). I'm looking forward to the challenge.